# Let $r \cdot u = s \cdot u$ exists in a vector space $V$. Show that if $r \ne s$, then $u = o$, the zero vector in $V$ and If $u \ne o$, then $r = s$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $r \cdot u = s \cdot u$ exists in a vector space $V$. Show that:

1. If $r \ne s$, then $u = o$, the zero vector in $V$.
2. If $u \ne o$, then $r = s$.

**EDIT:**

**Attempt:**
I know that this question is a little bit easy because it is a basic concept. But, although so,
I got a little confused about my answer below.

Let $r,s \in \Bbb F$, a field, and $u \in V$. Now,
\begin{align*}
r \cdot u &= s \cdot u \\
r \cdot u - s \cdot u &= o \\
(r-s) \cdot u &= o \\
\end{align*}

What next?

Assume that $V$ is over field, say $F$. Then, if $r \ne s$,
\begin{align*}
(r-s) \cdot (r-s)^{-1} \cdot u &= o \cdot (r-s)^{-1} \\
u &= o,
\end{align*}
and if $u \ne o$, then we must have $r-s = 0$ i.e. $r=s$.

Does it true?

Comment: I think you are true since it doesn't matter the result.

Comment: How exactly $(r-s) u = \textit{o} \implies r-s=0 \vee u=\textit{o}$?

Comment: @azif00 Em... Sorry? What do you mean?

Comment: @arnold How $(r-s)u = o$ *implies* $r-s=0$ or $u=o$? Also note that in the second and third equalities, the right hand side should be denoted as $\textit o$, since the left hand side is a vector, not a scalar.

Comment: @azif00 Oh, my bad. So, it must be $r \cdot u - s \cdot u = o$ and $(r-s) \cdot u = o$?
Then, can I conclude that $r-s = 0$ or $u = o$ directly? If not, why?

Comment: @Carlo In the question doesn't mention that $V = \Bbb F$. So, how?

Comment: @arnold In a field, every nonzero element has a multiplicative inverse. That does help you to conclude that $u=o$ using that $r-s \neq 0$.

Comment: @azif00 Does my edit true?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: You are correct so far, but you must explain why $(r - s) \mathbf u = \mathbf 0$ implies that $r - s = 0$ or $\mathbf u = \mathbf 0.$ Equivalently, we can show that if $r - s \neq 0,$ then $\mathbf u = \mathbf 0.$ Given that $r - s \neq 0$ and $r$ and $s$ are elements of a field, what can you say about $r - s?$ Is there a way to "cancel" $r - s$ from the left-hand side? Once you study bases, you may use the below argument. (It can't hurt to practice.)

---

Consider a basis $\mathscr B$ of $V.$ Every vector of $V$ can be written uniquely as a finite $\mathbb F$-linear combination of basis vectors of $V.$ Particularly, there exist unique scalars $c_1, \dots, c_n$ and basis vectors $\mathbf v_1, \dots, \mathbf v_n$ such that $\mathbf u = c_1 \mathbf v_1 + \cdots + c_n \mathbf v_n.$ Given that $r \mathbf u = s \mathbf u,$ we have that $$(r c_1) \mathbf v_1 + \cdots + (r c_n) \mathbf v_n = (s c_1) \mathbf v_1 + \cdots + (s c_n) \mathbf v_n.$$ What can you say about the relationship between $r c_i$ and $s c_i$ for each integer $1 \leq i \leq n?$ From there, I believe that you can conclude the desired results.

Comment: Unfortunately, the question is not in Basis chapter. It in the first chapter on vector space. So, there is no other approach that very simple?

Comment: I see that there is a more straightforward way. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I have edited my attempt. Does it true?

Comment: It is correct to multiply both sides by $(r - s)^{-1}$ whenever $r - s$ is nonzero. That is all there is to it. This is because $A \implies (B \vee C)$ and $(A \wedge \neg B) \implies C$ are logically equivalent. The upshot is that if you want to prove a statement "$A$ implies $B$ or $C$," then it suffices to assume "A and not $B$" and to prove that $C$ holds.

Comment: Well. How about the second condition? Is that hold? Sorry to ask and asking to you.

Comment: Yes, I got it right now. Thanks Sir!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the complete problem statement is:

> Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $F$. Suppose we have $ru=su$ for some $r,s\in F$ and $u\in V$. Show that $r=s$ or $u=0$.

Transform the equality to $(r-s)u=0$. Assume $r\ne s$. Then $r-s\ne 0$ and has a multiplicative inverse $\frac1{r-s}$ in $F$. It follows that $$u=1\cdot u=\frac1{r-s}\cdot(r-s)\cdot u=\frac1{r-s}\cdot 0=0.$$

Comment: This is exactly as I have written, is it not?

Answer (score -3):

I don't believe the question as posted is complete - unlike ordinary numbers, vector Dot Products do *not* have the cancellation property. From [Wikipedia article for Dot Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)

If $a ⋅ b = a ⋅ c$ and $a  ≠  0 $, then we can write: $ a  ⋅ ( b  −  c ) = 0$ by the [Distributive Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property); this just means that  $a$  is perpendicular to $( b  −  c )$, which still allows $( b  −  c ) ≠  0 $, and therefore allows $b  ≠  c $.

To put it another way, $r ⋅ u = s ⋅ u$ (with $r ≠ s$) can still be true if $u ⟂ (r - s)$ and $u ≠ 0$.

EDIT: Assuming a downvote means someone doesn't believe me, I'll work through a simple example with three perpendicular, non-zero unit vectors.

Let $r = (1,0,0)$, $s = (0,1,0)$, and $u = (0,0,1)$.

$$r ⋅ u = s ⋅ u$$
$$\left\lVert r \right\rVert \times  \left\lVert u \right\rVert \times \cos \theta_{ru} = \left\lVert s \right\rVert \times \left\lVert u \right\rVert \times \cos \theta_{su}$$
$$1 \times 1 \times \cos \theta_{ru} = 1 \times 1 \times \cos \theta_{su}$$
Obviously, being perpendicular unit vectors, $\theta_{ru} = \theta_{su} = 90^\circ$, so we get
$$1 \times 1 \times \cos 90 = 1 \times 1 \times \cos 90$$
$$1 \times 1 \times 0 = 1 \times 1 \times 0$$
$$0=0$$

Comment: This is not the vector dot product; the dot is scalar multiplication.

Comment: @Carlo ' ⋅ ' is the notation for a Vector Dot Product - a scalar multiplication would have no symbol or ' × '. OP has also clarified via edit th the question by stating that r and s are Vector Fields, (not scalars). In the original question it was implied that r, s, and u were all Vectors. With r and s now defined as vector fields the question is solvable, but there is no point updating a downvoted solution.

Comment: I disagree. Usually, in the context of linear algebra, the symbol $\cdot$ is used to denote the action $\cdot : R \times M \to M$ of a ring $R$ on an $R$-module $M.$ In the case that $R$ is a field, the $R$-module $M$ is a vector space, and the symbol $\cdot$ is scalar multiplication.